# Avoid already converted equation in htlatex

Tags: conversion, tex4ht, htlatex

I have converted big `LaTeX` file to `html` format successfully (include all the equations are converted to `png` format). After that I have changed some `LaTeX` text part. How do avoid again no need `equation` conversion in htlatex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images are converted by `t4ht` command, which has `-p` option for disable the conversion.  Options for `t4ht` are passed as fourth parameter for `htlatex`:

```
 htlatex filename "" "" " -p"
```

you need to use `""` for second and third parameters, when you don't use any options for `tex4ht.sty` and `tex4ht` command.