# Avoid already converted Figures in htlatex

Tags: graphics, tex4ht, htlatex

I have found how do avoid already converted equation in this link: [Avoid already converted equation in htlatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197001/avoid-already-converted-equation-in-htlatex). How to do the same method in Figures Conversion? My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

Sample Text here.

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{Figure1.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption here.}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{Fig2.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption here.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you post a `mwe`? I think `-p` option mentioned in the linked answer should suppress all image conversions

Comment: @michal.h21: I have updated my questions and when using `-p` also again Figure Image is converting to PNG format.

Comment: I see. Do you use some custom configuration for pdf to png conversion? This configuration would need to check whether the png file exists and is newer than the pdf. Maybe `GNU Make` could be used for this. Or some lua script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you use some configuration for converting `pdf` to `png` in your `cfg` file, like this one:

```
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% Various helper functions
% default font size
\newcommand\emwidth{16}
\let\emwidth\f@size
% convert pt to rem
\newcommand\CalcRem[1]{\strip@pt\dimexpr(#1)/\emwidth}

\Configure{graphics*}
  {pdf}
   {% you need to coonvert eps to png first
   \Needs{"convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
                           \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}% 
    \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
    \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
     \space style="width:\CalcRem{\Gin@req@width}em;"
   }%
  }
    \makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

this configuration converts `pdf` to `png` using `imagemagick`'s `convert` command and include `css` declaration for calculating image width in `em` units. The problem is that `\Needs` command is executed at every compilation. We can use simple lua script to check modification times of both input and output images and execute `convert` only when input is newer than output.

File `imgconvert.lua`:

```lua
-- usage: texlua imgconvert input_image output_image
-- this is needed to enable lfs library
kpse.set_program_name("luatex")

-- read file attributes of images to find modification times
local input = arg[1]
local attr_input = lfs.attributes(input)
if not attr_input then 
    print("Cannot read attributes for file: ".. input)
    os.exit(1)
end
local output = arg[2]
local attr_output = lfs.attributes(output) or {}

if attr_input.change > (attr_output.change or 0) then
  -- call convert command
  local command = string.format('convert %s %s', input, output)
  print(command)
  os.execute(command)
else
    print("Converted image ".. output .." is up-to-date")
end
```

As this is basically a wrapper for `convert` command, you can use this script for all image types supported by `imagemagick`.

Now we need to modify the `cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% Various helper functions
% default font size
\newcommand\emwidth{16}
\let\emwidth\f@size
% convert pt to rem
\newcommand\CalcRem[1]{\strip@pt\dimexpr(#1)/\emwidth}

\Configure{graphics*}
  {pdf}
   {% you need to coonvert eps to png first
   \Needs{"texlua imgconvert.lua \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
                           \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}% 
    \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
    \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
     \space style="width:\CalcRem{\Gin@req@width}em;"
   }%
  }
    \makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

and if you observe the compilation log, you will see:

```
System call: texlua imgconvert.lua Fifure1.pdf Fifure1.png
convert Fifure1.pdf Fifure1.png
System return: 0
System call: texlua imgconvert.lua Fig2.pdf Fig2.png
convert Fig2.pdf Fig2.png
System return: 0
```

and in later runs:

```
System call: texlua imgconvert.lua Fifure1.pdf Fifure1.png
Converted image Fifure1.png is up-to-date
System return: 0
System call: texlua imgconvert.lua Fig2.pdf Fig2.png
Converted image Fig2.png is up-to-date
System return: 0
```

Comment: I have received `imgconvert.lua:7: bad argument #1 to 'attributes' (string expected, got nil)`. How do solve this problem?

Comment: @Balaji could you take a look to the terminal output before this error message? at lines like: `System call: texlua imgconvert.lua Fifure1.pdf Fifure1.png`

Comment: I have used `call texlua imgcnv.lua page91-02.pdf page91-01.png` and received error are `imgcnv.lua:10: attempt to index local 'attr_output' (a nil value)`.

Comment: @Balaji see updated script